# how to search wildcard character like * and ? in solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solr-schema

For field type, currently using KeywordTokenizerFactory in schema.xml.

Field value is like **Good?man**. Suppose if i want to search with **?** then i need to get the value contains **?** i.e(**Good?man**). For that my query would be like ***\?***

But it is responding entire document from solr.

How to search wildcard character like ***** and **?** with wildcard search in solr?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) to convert symbols/numbers into unicode characters or use String field to index data and search it by escaping the characters.